Can I use a different external graphics card with CUDA or OpenVINO?
I would like to study machine learning. My laptop is a Huawei with an Intel Iris GPU. I want to add an external graphics card. Would NVIDIA be compatible with my laptop? Can I use the external GPU with CUDA or OpenVINO in Anaconda?

Short answer: Yes, Intel based computers and NVIDIA GPUs are compatible. You want to aim for the highest bandwidth connection your computer can manage. What model is your laptop?

The model is Huawei matebook x pro. There are two usb4 ports.

Which model year of the MateBook X Pro do you have? An eGPU should work regardless, but the level of performance you'll see could vary drastically depending on which one you have.

It is 2022 model Matebook with 12th intel i7 CPU.

Yes, Intel based computers are compatible with Nvidia and AMD GPUs. Yes, you can still make use of the CUDA cores in an eGPU to do non-graphics work.
The Huawei Matebook x Pro has 2 Thunderbolt 4 ports on the left side. You will want to look for an eGPU that uses Thunderbolt 4 to connect your GPU to the laptop. You may choose between simple adapters that require you to also have a power supply and supporting hardware, or an enclosed eGPU mounting solution. Both solutions require you to purchase the GPU separately. There are also self contained eGPUs (where the GPU is included with the enclosure) but these are less up-gradable and often based on the less powerful 'Mobile' model of the GPU.
